# Why does XCode 4 include the file extensions and @2x suffixes in the image lists?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, xcode4

In previous versin of XCode and IB, when I would specify a background image for a button, the image lists would just include the filenames without the file extensions or @2x suffixes and the iOS was smart enough to know which file to use depending on whether or not the device had a retina display.  Now in XCode 4, when I go to select an image for a button, it lists all the images in my project, including their file extensions and @2x suffixes.  Which one do I use?  If I choose the image without the @2x suffix, will iOS know to use the @2x version on devices with retina displays?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Just use the base name without extension or suffix, like you did in previous versions. The os will still figure it out at runtime. This may be a bug in Xcode, or apple decided it was better to show all of the full names.

Comment: I don't have that option, do you?  all the images in the drop down list have file extensions.

Comment: Does it let you type in something else? I haven't upgraded to Xcode 4 yet, but I assumed you would be able to type in something manually.

Comment: yeah, it does, but when i type in the image name without the extension, it can't find the image at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the ones that don't have @2x.  That seems to work great for me.  Like you I have no idea why apple decided to start including all file names in the results list.  It seems quite counter intuitive.

Comment: thanks, good to know.  the only reason I asked is i'm having issues with one of the buttons using the low-res version of an image on a retina device and I can't tell if it's something i'm doing wrong or if i'm not using the new XCode 4 correctly.

Comment: I think it's a good change. Sometimes, the @2x images are quite useful in an iPad target.